# Terminal opens with previous info in it

Tags: command-line

When i open new terminal window it isn't clear, somehow it stored this info and every time it shows this as a starting position. How can I clear this?

[image]

Comment: The text you show is output from your .profile, .bashrc (or similar for other shells). Find where tou are calling`brew' and fix the problem.

Comment: @SorenA Thanks a lot, I fixed it